# Option to get ntpd to run interactively

Tags: ntp, openbsd

I am trying to set up an NTP client on OpenBSD. There is a way to run `ntpd` 'interactively' so that it tries to connect to our NTP server immediatley and doesn't return until it has updated the time or failed to find the server, etc, logging the output to the console.

Can anyone remind me what it is please?

The options on our OpenBSD install are:

```
ntpd [-dSs] [-f file]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `-d` according to the [`man`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=man&sektion=1)ual page of [`ntpd`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ntpd&sektion=8).

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't get the output I wanted, and thought that I was somehow using the wrong option, but in fact it was a configuration issue with the network which had confused me!